# Recreating Eval Function

Tags: parsing, scheme, eval, racket, multiplication

I'm trying to duplicate the eval function in racket without calling upon the built-in eval function. I'm currently using a simple math lexer and parser

```
$(define simple-math-lexer
       (lexer
        ((re-+ number10) (token-NUM (string->number lexeme)))
        ("-" (token--))
        ("+" (token-+))
        ;; recursively calls the lexer which effectively skips whitespace
        (whitespace (simple-math-lexer input-port))
        ((eof) (token-EOF))))

(define simple-math-parser
       (parser
        (start exp)
        (end EOF)
        (error void)
        (tokens a b)
        (precs (left - +))
        (grammar
         (exp ((NUM) $1)
              ((+ exp exp) (+ $2 $3))
              ((- exp exp) (- $2 $3))))))
```

at the moment I'm not sure how I would implement multiplication for the parser.
Any suggestions or links to help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). With the little information provided in the question I can suggest to:

- Separate the evaluation from the parsing, an evaluator should receive a list of symbols ready to be evaluated, here it appears that you´re mixing the parsing and evaluation phases
- Simply add another case, in the same way that you're handling addition and subtraction you could include multiplication: `((* exp exp) (* $2 $3))`

[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1) is a very good book for getting you started on how to write your own evaluator in Scheme.